# Proving from Hilbert axioms in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am using axioms similar to the Hilbert system of logical axioms:

\begin{align}
&P\rightarrow (Q\rightarrow P)  \tag{A1}\\[5pt]
&(P\rightarrow (Q\rightarrow R))\rightarrow ((P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)) \tag{A2}\\[5pt]
&(\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P)\rightarrow (P\rightarrow Q) \tag{A3}
\end{align}

I may also use Modus Ponens and the deduction theorem. I am trying to prove two things:

$(a)\;\;\; \vdash \neg P \rightarrow (\neg Q\rightarrow (P\rightarrow R))$

$(b)\;\;\; \vdash (P \rightarrow ¬P) → (\neg\neg P \rightarrow \neg P)$

I know what I am supposed to do but I just can't quite get there with either one. I tried use deduction theorem in both so I am trying to prove in $(a)$ that $\neg P \vdash (\neg Q\rightarrow (P\rightarrow R))$ and similarly in $(b)$. Here is my effort for $(a)$:

\begin{align}
&1. \neg P  &&\text{premise}\\[5pt]
&2. \neg P \rightarrow (\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P) &&(A1)\\[5pt]
&3. (\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P) &&MP:1+2\\[5pt]
&4. (\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q) &&(A3)\\[5pt]
&5. P \rightarrow Q  &&MP:3+4
\end{align}

I don't know how to proceed. Feels like I have all the needed pieces but I can't put them together. I have quite a similar situation with $(b)$. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the edits I just made, there are much easier ways to do the alignment/tagging than adding manual spacing until it looks right.

Comment: You seem to me to have proved (use MP once more) that $\{P,\neg P\}\vdash Q$ for any $Q$ in particular $\{P,\neg P\}\vdash R$. For (a) by DT three times all you need to prove is $\{P,\neg P, Q\}\vdash R$, so you're there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A)Use deduction theorem twice. So then you have to show that $\neg P,\neg Q\vdash_{ax}P\rightarrow R$. You are almost done, you only need to show that $\vdash_{ax}P\rightarrow(Q \rightarrow R)$ and apply MP.

B) Use deduction theorem once and notice that by axiom $A2$ $(\neg\neg P\rightarrow(P \rightarrow \neg P)) \rightarrow ((\neg\neg P \rightarrow P) \rightarrow (\neg\neg P \rightarrow \neg P))$. Then by axiom $A1$ $(P \rightarrow \neg P) \rightarrow (\neg\neg P\rightarrow (P \rightarrow \neg P))$. I think you are able to finish from here.

Comment: Am I not supposed to show in (a) that $\neg P, \neg Q \vdash P\rightarrow R$? Does your hint work anyway? In (b) I got to $\vdash (\neg\neg P \rightarrow P)\rightarrow (\neg \neg P\rightarrow \neg P))$ so I would need to prove $\vdash (\neg\neg P \rightarrow P)$ in order to finish with MP but how can I do that?

Comment: $\neg P$, $\neg Q\vdash_{ax}P \rightarrow R \iff \neg P \vdash_{ax}Q\rightarrow(P \rightarrow R)$ by deduction theorem.

Comment: Where do you lose the negation symbol? Deduction theorem says that $\Gamma\cup \{P\}\vdash Q \iff \Gamma \vdash P\rightarrow Q$

Comment: It was a typo and i cant edit the post  anymore :D So it should be $\neg P, \neg Q \vdash_{ax} P\rightarrow R \iff \neg P \vdash_{ax}\neg Q \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)$.

Comment: I thought so :), but anyway I finished (b) with your hints but I don't understand the hints for (a) so maybe you could make them a little more precise? And you also have the same typo in your answer and I don't know if that is an accident or does it affect anything

Comment: About $\vdash_{ax}\neg\neg P \rightarrow P$. We know that $P,\neg P \vdash_{ax} Q$ for all $P,Q$ so by deduction theorem $\vdash_{ax}\neg P \rightarrow (P \rightarrow Q)$. Using the previous result you can easily show that $\vdash_{ax}\neg\neg P \rightarrow P$.

Comment: By axiom $A2$ we have $(P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)) \rightarrow ((P \rightarrow Q)\rightarrow(P \rightarrow R))$ where you need  $\vdash_{ax}P\rightarrow(Q\rightarrow R)$. Remember you already have $\vdash_{ax}P\rightarrow Q$!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119539/discussion-between-laabibibi-and-slave-of-christ).